# Can the Object literal take values other than key value pair?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

my so far understanding with object literal is we can use it like the key value pair, where key is the property and the value can be a actual value, a function or a anonymous function

```
 function a() {
  return 'value b';
}

var result = {
  'keya': 'valueA',
  'keyb': a,
  'keyc': function () {
    console.log('some value');
  }
```

};

till i read this block of [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Examples)

```
var obj = {
  log: ['test'],
  get latest() {
    if (this.log.length == 0) return undefined;
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
}
console.log(obj.latest); // Will return "test".
```

my question is, in the above code the function latest() doesnt have any key then how can it be used inside a object literal, am i missing something

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ES6 (which is also called ES2015) syntax, it's a newer version of Javascript that lets you do this.

You would've had to have the key there in ES5 code.

Comment: Here's a pretty good rundown of ES6 and objects: http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/